# Why does power of two >62 in bash output negative values or zero?

Tags: bash

If I use a larger integer than 62 for power of two in bash(4.0.33(0)-release), then following happens:

```
$ time echo $((2**60))
1152921504606846976

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
$ time echo $((2**61))
2305843009213693952

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
$ time echo $((2**62))
4611686018427387904

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
$ time echo $((2**63))
-9223372036854775808

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
$ time echo $((2**64))
0

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
$ time echo $((2**65))
0

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
$
```

I guess that's related to two's complement? However, could somebody explain in more detail why does bash behave in a way it does?

Comment: [Signed integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Comment: Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculations are being made on signed 64 bit integers. Therefor

- 2^62 is in positive range of 64 bit signed integer
- 2^63 is lowest negative 64 bit signed integer as it is over highest positive 2^63-1
- 2^64 and greater results in overflow and 0 is displayed

---

Python offers your better handling of large numbers than bash.

```
$ python -c 'print 2**256'
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936
```

Comment: `bc` has less overhead for doing basic calculations than Python: `BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc -l <<<"2^256"`

Comment: @Grzegorz And bash on this particular system was compiled in a way that it supports max 64 bit signed and unsigned integers? In addition, I still quite don't understand this 2^63 output. I mean why does this output lowest negative value while for example 2^61 don't. In addition, 2^63 should be 9223372036854775808 not the -9223372036854775808?

Comment: @Martin This is because of [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) used in signed integers representation.